# display and view geofencing in googlemaps using ionic2

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-geofence

i am developing an ionic 2 application, i am coding on a geofencing feature using ionic native geofence, i am able to set geofence radius data and get current location, but unable to to view it visually on google map, have included screenshot of desired output below

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-range [(ngModel)]="formData.radius" ngControl="radius" name="radius" #radius="ngModel" min="40" max="200" color="primary" pin="true" snaps="true" step="10">
   </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Geolocation, Geofence } from 'ionic-native';

export class PlaceAddPage {
 radius:number = 100;

 constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // initialize the plugin
  Geofence.initialize().then(
    // resolved promise does not return a value
    () => console.log('Geofence Plugin Ready'),
    (err) => console.log(err)
   )
  })
 }


 initMap() {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
   let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
   let latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0608842, 80.2221805);
   let GooleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapfence'), {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15
   });
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: GooleMap,
    title: 'My Location',
   });
  });
 }
}
```

**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: What is the output you are getting now? Is there any errors in console.log?

Comment: @MurshidAhmed i am just able to get geofence ready, not able to display the fence in map

Comment: By mentioning fence did you mean the circle or something else

Comment: @Stallion i mean the circle by mentioning fence

Comment: @RohitKumarVinay please go through this link https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence/tree/master/src/pages/geofence-details

Comment: @sai I already went through that, it uses leaflet plugin, any chance I can use just plain Google maps?

Comment: @RohitKumarVinay okay, but i didn't find any id in html named as "mapfence"

Comment: @sai,i have added it in my code, it was pretty obvious so did not add, i need ionic2 geofence with just native ionic geofence and google maps

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement above plugin then you have to do a lot more things and import more plugins too.One such root plugin is `import * as Leaflet from "leaflet";`.

On below Git repo, they have implemented it perfectly for Ionic 2.So go ahead and play with it.It is working fine for me.If you have any issue please comment below.

**Play with** [**Git repo**](https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want Geo-fence using Google maps API please go through  [Ionic2 Geofence using Google maps api](https://github.com/IonicUser/Ionic2_Geofence_GoogleMaps)